# What is the meaning of the phrase 'listing off'?

Tags: meaning, phrases, errors

> services
>
> Listing off registered services (nova-scheduler, nova-compute and so on) and their current state.
> The updated_at field is used to determine if a given service is considered healthy or not.

“services” is a database table. If you don’t known what a database table is, think of it as a listing.

Comment: My guess was: listing somewhere other than the registered services.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[list someone or something off](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/list+off):

> to recite a list of people or things, one by one.

Comment: It's still quite common that someone in the IT department will *list off* some selected details as a one-off paper report, so a front-office worker can trawl through the items sorting something out.

Comment: I can attest to this being correct, too. It's commonly used in the UK.

Answer (score 2):

It means that the writer misspelled “of” as “off”.

The asker is quoting a data dictionary.* The data dictionary lists the name of each field and what it contains. The field in question (the `services` field) contains a

> Listing **off* registered services (nova-scheduler, nova-compute and so on) and their current state.

This is awkward, and as soon the extra *f* is removed, the awkwardness is gone. The field then contains a

> Listing *of* registered services (nova-scheduler, nova-compute and so on) and their current state.

Others have pointed out that *to list off* is a verb phrase meaning to recite from a list. This is quite true. But in this context a verb phrase makes no sense. In a description of what a field contains, you expect an object (a *list*), not a verb (to *list*).

Still, I suppose it is possible the author intended that the field contains the result when you *list off*, what you might describe as a *listing-off*. But then you need the hyphen, and you still need the word *of* to connect it to the rest of the sentence: the field contains a

> *Listing-off of* registered services (nova-scheduler, nova-compute and so on) and their current state.

If the OP is still in doubt of what was intended I suggest contacting the author.

---

<sup>* The excerpt is taken from the O’Reilly nutshell handbook *Deploying OpenStack*.</sup>

Comment: No it doesn't. I can list off [numerous examples](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=list+them+off&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) where 'off' is exactly what was meant.

Comment: @FumbleFingers — I think it's clear from the context of the question that the phrase should be *listing of*. The description is not describing an action, it is describing a noun.

Comment: It is extracted from Deploying OpenStack exactlty. BTW, What 'OP' stands for?

Comment: OP means Original Poster -- the person who posted the question.

Comment: I don't have the rest of the handbook, which might make things clearer, but from what OP has quoted, it seems equally possible the "heading" *services* could simply be followed by a list of *actions*. But it makes no difference to the meaning either way, and that's what was asked for.